# C++ Linked List of Different SubClasses

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on making a memory pool for a project, however I am having issues compiling it:

I have a memory pool class (in the example below R), which has a template parameter to hold the actual class used. Each class is a subclass of Descriptor.

I assumed I can make a linked list of R objects, however the compiler is complaining about the type casting when I try to append an R class containing a sub class of descriptor.

Any suggestions on how to fix this compile error?

```
 g++-4.7  -g -ggdb -DDEBUG=1   -Wall -std=c++11   -march=native -m64 -DINTEL -fno-strict-aliasing example.cpp -o example.x
example.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void n1::n2::R<D>::add() [with D = n1::n2::SubDescriptor2<int, int>]’:
example.cpp:68:14:   required from here
example.cpp:37:10: error: cannot convert ‘n1::n2::R<n1::n2::SubDescriptor2<int, int> >* const’ to ‘n1::n2::R<n1::n2::Descriptor>*’ in assignment
example.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void n1::n2::R<D>::add() [with D = n1::n3::SubDescriptor<int, int>]’:
example.cpp:72:13:   required from here
example.cpp:37:10: error: cannot convert ‘n1::n2::R<n1::n3::SubDescriptor<int, int> >* const’ to ‘n1::n2::R<n1::n2::Descriptor>*’ in assignment
```

working example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <stdlib.h>
namespace n1 {
  namespace n2 {
    class Descriptor;
    template<class D>
    class R;


    class Descriptor {
        public:
          int temp;

          Descriptor() {}
          Descriptor(int x) {
            temp = x;
          }
          ~Descriptor() {}
    };

    R<Descriptor> * list = nullptr;

    template<class D>
    class R {
    public:
      R<Descriptor> *pool_next;
      D descriptor; //EDIT for some reason I only had d here...

      template<typename... Args>
      R(Args&&... args): descriptor(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
      };


      void add() {
         this->pool_next = list;
         list = this;
      }
    };

    template<class T, class W>
      class SubDescriptor2: public Descriptor {
      public:
        SubDescriptor2(int x) {
          temp = x;
        };
        ~SubDescriptor2() {};
      };
  };


  namespace n3{
  template<class T, class W>
    class SubDescriptor: public n2::Descriptor {
    public:
        SubDescriptor(int x) {
          temp = x;
        };
        ~SubDescriptor() {};
    };
  };
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  n1::n2::R<  n1::n2::SubDescriptor2<int, int>  > *temp2;
  temp2 = new n1::n2::R<  n1::n2::SubDescriptor2<int, int>  >(1);
  temp2->add();

  n1::n2::R<  n1::n3::SubDescriptor<int, int> > *temp;
  temp = new n1::n2::R< n1::n3::SubDescriptor<int, int> >(1);
  temp->add();
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I see at least 2 other compile errors with the same command invocation. I'm pretty sure you have to fix those first.

Comment: I am not getting any other errors, can you post your errors?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you're compiling? Here are two more:
const.cc:31:26: error: member initializer 'descriptor' does not name a non-static data member or base class
      R(Args&&... args): descriptor(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
const.cc:37:15: error: assigning to 'R<n1::n2::Descriptor> *' from incompatible type 'n1::n2::R<n1::n2::SubDescriptor2<int, int> > *'
         list = this;

Comment: Fixed, sorry I must have accidently erased part of a variable declaration, code has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R<SubDescriptor>` is not a subclass of `R<Descriptor>`. That's because C++ templates are not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

First thing I can think of as a solution is to keep a `Descriptor*` in the R class, instantiate all Rs with a Descriptor as their template parameter, and pass different subclasses of Descriptor when costructing a new R.

Comment: Makes sense, but it wont work for my use case, I want R and Descriptor to be co-located in the memory pool as to avoid extra levels of pointer indirection....Thanks for the link and the explanation.
In my application I require the sizeof all descriptor objects to be less than a cacheline, and each R allocated is forced to be cacheline size. Would casting it have a negative affect on calls to virtual functions?

Comment: I can't answer with certainty on the casting question, but I wouldn't do it. How about something like this: class RBase { virtual Descriptor* getDescriptor() = 0; } and then template<typename D> class R: RBase? This will add another virtual pointer to the memory requirements.